# When was the ISS's "SPEED LIMIT 17500 MPH" sign originally posted?

Tags: iss, space-shuttle, history

When was the ISS's "SPEED LIMIT 17500 MPH" sign originally posted?

[image: Astronaut Ellen Ochoa going 17,500 mph]

**above:** "STS110-353-012 (8-19 April 2002) --- [Astronaut Ellen Ochoa](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/about/people/orgs/bios/ochoa.html), STS-110 mission specialist, poses by the speed limit signs in the Unity node on the International Space Station (ISS)." from [here](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-110/html/sts110-353-012.html).

I used this in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31365/12102) but I'd like to know more. It seems many astronauts "happened to have" had their picture or video taken in front of the sign over the years. I'm curious how far back it goes, and wondering if it counts as "original equipment".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not original, but close.

If we view the original hi-res [photo](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-110/hires/sts110-353-012.jpg) used in the question we can see the salmon color behind crew member Ellen Ochoa. This tells us that the hatch in question is the Node 1 aft hatch (it leads to the Russian module FGB).

We can see in this photo from STS-88, the first Shuttle ISS assembly flight, that the same hatch is not yet decorated with the signs.

[image]

The signs appear on the next mission, STS-96. They have not yet been affixed in this photo.  I note that some of the signs are differently colored from the question in the photo (which was taken on STS-110), so they may have been replaced at a later date. A brief review of other missions does not show the signs permanently in place until STS-110, Ellen Ochoa's next mission to the ISS. Perhaps she was the creator of the signs.

[image]

Images from the old, mostly abandoned, NASA site [nasa.spaceflight.gov](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/home/index.html).

Comment: As much as I love that first picture, honesty compels me to replace it, because I noticed it was of the wrong hatch, darn it.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for time-stamping this iconic bit of space history.

Comment: By coincidence, NASA just released today a YouTube video using that iconic sign in the title: [Space Station Science at 17,500 Miles Per Hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxlvbFOIXUk)

Comment: @Uhoh controls the media - as you once remarked about me!