# Have astronauts seen Starlink trains?

Tags: iss, starlink, visibility-of-spacecraft

Starlink satellites move in the same altitude region as the ISS (on their way up and eventually back down) and are particularly noticeable for weeks after deployment as "trains".

Have one of these trains been spotted by astronauts on the ISS?

Considering the potential vantage point in Earth's shadow looking towards the direction where the Sun has just set or will soon rise, it's seems like this is inevitable.

Comment: One factor that would complicate seeing this from the ISS is that a large part of why the satellites are so visible is that just before dawn (or after dusk), an object overhead can reflect the sun since the sun hasn't set on it yet. This is optimal viewing conditions since everything except the satellite is dark. This won't happen from a space based observer nearly as much.

Comment: OscarSmith I think the geometry can work; the ISS could be in Earth's shadow and easily see LEO objects if they were bright enough, and they have several flat reflective surfaces that these days are oriented during raising *to avoid reflecting towards Earth* so no need to view them overhead for them to be bright necessarily. I have a hunch that SpaceX could even choreograph a light show for ISS specifically using synchronized attitude controls if they wanted to.

Comment: Out of curiosity: have you tried to google "starlink iss" (a.k.a "show any research effort") just to see pictures of starlink satellites taken from ISS-astronauts ;-) ?

Comment: @CallMeTom for a small fraction of my questions I may already know an answer but suspect there may be a better one out there writable by someone more familliar with the topic. The goal is to facilitate good answers. In general my questions are well researched but in this case it's just not necessary. A good answer may also be the source of interesting follow-up questions.

Comment: I wrote a quick answer, but indeed a simple Google search would have provided OP with an answer ;)

Comment: @yzokras but now you have provided an answer for all readers, not just me.

Comment: @CallMeTom I've added another anwer

Comment: -1 if you know the answer, post it at the same time. that's what the answer this question tick box is for

Comment: @JCRM 1) I could imagine *an answer but of course that didn't mean that it would turn out to be *the* answer, and it turned out it wasn't! I won't tell you which of these two *very different* answers I was thinking along the lines of, and which one surprised me afterward! 2) *What* tick box?

Comment: The one at the bottom, labelled "
Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style
"

Comment: @JCRM oh [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiJJt.png) which links to [t’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/); I'd never really paid attention to that. It seems to disappear once the question is first posted. But I'm happier that a relatively new user picked up a little reputation. I don't see any rules that state one must answer one's own question if one thinks one might know the answer. I think my way is also just fine.

Comment: think "if you might know the answer" suggests one might have done a little more research before asking the question

Comment: @JCRM have a nice day! :-)

Comment: I have a vid recorded from the ISS Live stream HD camera on a dawn that is most likely one of the starlink trains passing by. I tracked both and their position was exactly what I saw. About 30 km away (highest ISS 30 km). My only question would be whether it could be the starlink by the distance.

Comment: @Apaiss if you can post all the relevant information which is mostly the time that the video represents and a screen shot, that can be checked based on the TLEs of the ISS and satellites. But if you don't know the time that the ISS Live stream was being generated, then it probably can't be checked.

Comment: Cool, I have this data. I will do it soon. I recorded a video with the tracker showing both (ISS and possibly the train) on the satflare, with day and time data, from the moment of the sighting. Thank you!

Comment: @uhoh, I have a strong suspicion that it was the starlinks, do I put my material here or open a new question about it by asking the opinion of colleagues? I not sure about what to do.

Comment: @Apaiss In this case maybe ask a new question first. In that case you can explain what you've got, what you think it is and ask if the identification is likely to be correct or not. Based on further input you can consider posting a supplemental answer here. Since the question asks if astronauts have seen them, a recording by an automated camera doesn't exactly count though, so I think starting with a new question is the best first step.

Comment: @uhoh Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it happened at least on 13th April 2020 at 21:25:02 UTC:

- https://sattrackcam.blogspot.com/2020/04/starlink-train-photographed-from.html

> The image above (image ISS062-E-148365, [original at high resolution here](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/SearchPhotos/photo.pl?mission=ISS062&roll=E&frame=148365)) was shot from the International Space Station (ISS) on 13 April 2020, 21:25:02 UT. It shows the Aurora Australis (southern lights) and a train of SpaceX Starlink satellites.
>
> The presence of the Starlink train in this image was first noted by Twitter user Riccardo Rossi (@RikyUnreal) and brought to my attention by Huub Eggen (@phi48). It is present in two earlier images as well, taken the preceeding minute (images ISS062-E-148363 and ISS062-E-148364).
>
> ISS was at 48.25 S, 81.03 E and 440 km altitude at the time the photo above was taken. With this information, I came to the following probable satellite ID's (annotations in image below) for the objects in the imaged "train": these are all objects from the 17 February 2020 launch ("Starlink 4").

[image]

Comment: `+1` Thanks! I like the 2nd image in the blog post showing the tentative identifications. We can probably call these Starlinks because "if not, what else?" but it's better to see that their apparent position and time corresponds with known TLE data.

Comment: This is by far the most epic photograph of a Starlink train.

Answer (score -1):

> Have astronauts seen Starlink trains?

### Technically, No.

Of course [@X's affirmative answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43940/12102) is basically right, but viewed from Space at [17500 MPH](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31366/12102) things move differently.

Since the ISS is moving just as fast as they are and in a different direction, the apparent motion of the satellites is oblique to the orbit they travel on.

Seen this way it's not a "train" with each satellite as a car moving (roughly) along the same track, but instead looks more like [echelon formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echelon_formation) flying.

See also [here](http://www.petester.com/html/t37fourship.html)

Cropped and rotated NASA photo ID: ISS062-E-148365 from [here](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/SearchPhotos/photo.pl?mission=ISS062&roll=E&frame=148365)

[image: Cropped and rotated NASA photo ID: ISS062-E-148365]

Example: USAF Fighter School Acrojets demonstration team - 1950, flying in echelon formation [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USAF_Fighter_School_Acrojets_demonstration_team_-_1950.jpg)

[image: USAF Fighter School Acrojets demonstration team - 1950, flying in echelon formation]

Comment: I had to re-read the answer. I think this answer might give people [who are reading in haste] the wrong idea that you're dismissing that orbital photograph as a formation-flying squadron of jets. Could you reword it? (P.S. I'm not the downvoter :)

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer I don't know how to write for people who are reading in haste any better than this; the first sentence says the other answer is basically right, the second sentence "the apparent motion of the satellites is oblique to the orbit they travel on" calls the satellites *satellites*. I will make the image illustrating the echelon formation smaller.

Comment: Much better! :)

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer thanks! Please feel free to edit further, sometimes I don't have a good feel for how things look to other readers, especially the "hasty" ones ;-)

Comment: ... so if you cross a bridge over a train track while the train is passing under the bridge, you don't see a train, because your relative motion stops it from being one. Right.

Comment: @JCRM *it's the tracks* that fool us; that and the fact that the cars are extended, resolved objects that are connected. These satellites are unresolved points